# Camera is not opening to scan Barcode in SAP UI5

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, sapui5, barcode-scanner

I am designing SAP UI5 application to scan a Barcode. Home Screen contains a Button, on click of it Camera should look for Barcode. But my Camera is not at all opening.Below is my controller code-

```
_Scanner : function(oEvent){
             alert("looking for camera");
             cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(

                      function (result) {

                          alert("We got a barcode" + result.text);

                      },

                      function (error) {

                          alert("Scanning failed: "+error);

                      }

                   );
             alert("will look for camera2");
                  }
```

index.html

```
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”cordova.js”></script>

<script type=”text/javascript” src=”js/index.js”></script>
```

I am adding barcode plugin using below command-
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-barcodescanner (it is adding successfully in cmd)

I am testing this application on Android v6. let me know the solution

Comment: You must me getting "Cordova not found" error in console, this is because SAPUI5 framework is used to develop web based application and it seems that you are trying to connect SAPUI5 with android mobile, for that you need to develop sapui5 in **Cordova** applciation  which will act as a connector between SAPUI5 and can access the camera function of mobile device

Comment: Yes, I am creating cordova android project. i added barcode plugin, using       cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-barcodescanner  but camera is not opening on my device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used device ready function. Now, it is working